# Hiding the argument type of std::function

Tags: c++

I have two objects, `Higher` and `Lower`. I don't want `Lower` to know about `Higher`.

My goal is to pass a function to object `Lower` that takes a pointer to a `Higher` and I don't want to reveal that type to `Lower`. My idea is to cast `Higher*` to `void*`.

Here's my non-functional attempt at implementing this:

```cpp
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct Higher {
    int val;
};

void foo(Higher* context) {
    int val = context->val;
}

struct Lower {
    std::function<void(void*)> m_function;
    
    Lower(std::function<void(void*)> function) : m_function(function) {}
};

int main()
{
    Higher context;
    
    std::function<void(void*)> foo_void = [foo] (void* context) {
        foo(static_cast<Higher*>(context));    
    };
    
    Lower lower(foo_void);
    lower.m_function(static_cast<void*>(&context));

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Here's a template implementation as suggested by [Silvio Mayolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2288659/silvio-mayolo) that doesn't quite work because the real code is a little different from the simplified example I've provided in the OP. I can't change the signature of `bar()` or make it a member method of `Lower`.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

struct Higher {
    int val;
};

void foo(Higher* context) {
    int val = context->val;
}

// ---------------------------------

void bar(void* context) {
    // A problem, can't access T here
    auto big_context = static_cast<std::pair<Lower*, T*>*>(context);
    big_context->first->m_function(big_context->second);
}

template<typename T>
struct Lower {
    std::function<void(T*)> m_function;
    T* m_context;
    
    Lower(std::function<void(T*)> function, T* context) 
        : m_function(function)
        , m_context(context)
    {
        std::pair<Lower*, T*> big_context = {this, m_context};
        bar(static_cast<void*>(&big_context));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Higher context;
    Lower<Higher> lower(foo, &context);

    return 0;
}
```

How would you actually implement it?

Comment: Not letting `Lower` see the *implementation* of `Higher` is one thing, but not wanting it to know the *name*? If you want `Lower` to work with any type, consider using a template so the type of the function argument is generic. But hiding it for the sake of hiding (and using `void*` and static casts to do it) is just forfeiting type safety for no reason.

Comment: We may also capture `Higher` into lambda, and use `std::function<void(void)> m_function`

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I've posted a templated implementation which is how I understand your suggestion.

Comment: That looks like a reasonable implementation and is more or less what I was suggesting. Does that work for your use case?

Comment: Actually, no, I don't think I can use templates in the non-simplified case as at some point I have to pass `context` via a `void*` to a function whose signature I can't change. And inside that function, I can't access the template type since it's not a member function.

Answer (score 2):

The only error in your initial sample was `capture of non-variable 'foo'`. If you remove the `foo` capture, [it is functional](https://godbolt.org/z/M76zezEM9).

In the second sample, the argument is available at the time the function is constructed (you chose to pass them both in the constructor), so you can instead just bind the argument immediately and save a `std::function<void()>`. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/Wcj4K4xPn).

Because the signature of the function taking a single `void*` is something you cannot change, according to the question and that has to hide something invocable, the most flexible option is to pass a pointer to a `std::function<void()>`.